# Efficiently query an embedded database in a loop with prepared statements

Tags: java, query-optimization, h2, derby, java-stored-procedures

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45023444/7419673) the other day but have since realized I was getting ahead of myself. I'm seeking advice on the proper way to handle the following scenario. I'm trying to `SELECT` the correct longitude and latitude for a given address and city, in the fastest way possible.

My `COORDINATES` table has 25,000 rows and looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have a Java `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>` which contains an `Integer` as the key, and an `ArrayList` containing **2** entries, an address and city. The `HashMap` has a size of 500.

There are 4 different types of `SELECT` statements I need to use, since each one is a little more lenient than the previous, like so:

```
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM coordinates WHERE(address::text = ? AND community::text = ?) 
UNION ALL
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM coordinates WHERE (address::text = ? AND community::text LIKE ?)
UNION ALL
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM coordinates WHERE (address::text LIKE ? AND community::text = ?)
UNION ALL
SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM coordinates WHERE (address::text LIKE ? AND community::text LIKE ?)
```

Notice the use of `LIKE` and `=`. Also notice I'm using `UNION ALL` which aggregates all the results, whereas I'm actually only interested in the single, best matching result as to avoid continuing to query if a match is found. Perhaps a `LIMIT` could be helpful.

If I merely loop through my `HashMap` and hit the database 500+ times (with a 4-part query)... that seems painfully inefficent since I'm not leveraging the SQL server. It's taking over a minute right now. I'm using H2 as my embedded DB but am willing to use Derby or Hyper if needed.

- What is the fastest way to loop through the `HashMap` and retrieve the corresponding, best matching longitude/latitude (if any) for each entry? Notice I have to match up `?` in the prepared statements with the corresponding address and city for each entry. Once again, you can view my current approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45023444/7419673).
- I'm leaning toward a stored procedure but the tutorials [like this](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/07/java-stored-procedures-with-derby/) mention creating a `JAR` file of the stored procedure's class and then installing it to Derby. How do you deploy a standalone Java app that has an embedded DB relying on `JAR` stored procedure?

Comment: I'm open to hear any feedback, even if not a direct answer. Please help!